# Setting up Certificates, Provisioning Profiles, and Code Signing from Beginning to End

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store, code-signing, xcode4.5

I feel like I've been formerly introduced into "App Signing Hell". For the life of me I can't Export my iPhone application from Xcode (4.5.1) to the App Store.

Let's assume I have deleted all of my certificates, Provisioning Profiles, keys, etc.

Every guide, youtube video, or blog I've found so far is an outdated step-by-step guide or paraphrased guide.

What steps do I need to take to export my App to a .ipa? What options do I need to select under the debug/release options under the "Code Signing" options of my project?

Comment: i assume you have a valid provisioning profile. if so are you trying to upload your app to app store through archiving? the reason i am asking is i can help you if i know where the issue is. could you please let me know so i can offer some help.

Comment: Did you try Apple's Technote TN2250: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html on troubleshooting code signing?

Comment: @adrian, Yes, I am trying to upload through archiving.

Comment: Was my answer helpful or do you need anymore help my friend?

Answer (score 0):

although this is not a programing question and should be asked on other forums, but i understand how frustrating it can be to be stuck in this hell. we all have been there. so below is the 7 easy steps of how to archive and upload to app store.

here is the rundown of archiving:

1- on the left pane select the name of your project and then select the project at the middle not target.
2- in configuration highlight release and press the plus sign button underneath it to copy that.
3- in the popup select duplicate release and while highlighted change that to distribution.
4-underneath it for use for command line select distribution
5-now on top select product-> edit scheme and then select archive. on the right hand side change the build configuration to distribution. make sure reveal the archive in organizer is check marked also. 
6- back in project level (see 1) select build setting and then go down to code signing and select distribution and from the drop down menu select your distribution profile. in this section i always select the automatic profile.
7- on the of the project where you select the simulator, select ios device.
that should take care of the issue for you. bare in mind this is the ios 6 archiving.